# DatePart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datepart

How do I get the values of days (Sunday to Saturday) using DatePart in .NET? My idea is, if it is a Saturday or Sunday, I have to skip the loop.

Comment: DatePart is a T-SQL function. Do you mean DateTime?

Comment: @penfold, the thing is I have a fromDate and a toDate. I have to loop within this range, find out if its a Saturday/Sunday and if that's the case, I got to break the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a date range you could try:

```
for(var curr_date = fromDate; curr_date <= toDate; curr_date.AddDays(1))
{
  if (curr_date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || 
      curr_date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
  {
     break;
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (true)
{
   if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
       || DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: the thing is I have a fromDate and a toDate. I have to loop within this range, find out if its a Saturday/Sunday and if that's the case, I got to break the loop.

Comment: Can you please post your code? So that we could make the correction(s).

Comment: `Dim stDate As DateTime = txtFromDate.Text  
        Dim enDate As DateTime = txtToDate.Text  
        Dim stDay As Integer = 2  
        While stDate <= enDate  
            If DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, stDate) = 7 Or   DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, stDate) = 6 Then
                GoTo Inc_DateInfo  
            End If  
            For p = 2 To gvTimeTable.Columns.Count - 2  
                Dim day = DatePart(DateInterval.Day, stDate)  `

Answer (score 0):

```
 string s = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    if (s == "Saturday")
    {
      //Your code     
    }
```

you can add your condition appropriate to the application